# The Signature of a Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, symmetric-matrices

Given a symmetric matrix $A$ and its corresponding signature, what information does the signature reveal about the matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature indicates the number of positive, negative and zero eigenvalues.

Refer also to: [Metric signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_signature).

Comment: Is that all that it reveals though?

Comment: Yes it is the only information given by signature.